# how to blur a 2d shape drawn on android using opengl es 2.0

Tags: android, opengl-es, bitmap, blur

How can I blur a 2d shape that is drawn on android using opengl es 2.0?  I have tried taking the screenshot using GLreadpixels() and then feeding that bitmap to my blur algo but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I would render the starting image into a texture attached to an FBO.  Then, you can read the captured image into a fragment shader and perform a blur effect there by combining multiple sampler2D samples at various neighboring texture coordinates.  This algorithm could be run multiple times very fast because the glReadPixels() is only needed once at the end.